# Why the insistence on who has the most dice after removals?

Tags: ninja-all-stars

In Ninja All-Stars, combat is resolved by each player throwing the amount of dice specified by the combatants' stats and any bonuses coming from the conditions, then matched dice are removed, then the one who has the most dice remaining chooses which of their dice to be the result.

Except... the rulebook is insistent that the decision of who gets to decide is made **after** the dice pairs are removed, but since those only ever remove one dice from each player, that shouldn't ever change anything - what am I missing?

Comment: In your use of words, it looks to me that you think that **dice** is singular, but it is actually a plural noun, the singular noun would be **die**. So the answer says that you must remove all the die that eliminate each other. So you remove at least 2 dice not 1 die.

Comment: 1 die from each player's pool of rolled dice, which means that there an never be any change in whose dice pool is larger.

Comment: 1 die from each players pool that matches another die in the other players pool which means that multiple dice can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Because the dice that are eliminated could eliminate possible results of the since every matching pair must be removed not just one dice from every player.

When they say all possible eliminations must be made, they mean that for each attacker/defender die elimination you can make, you must make that elimination. It is not trying to say that an attacker's own dice can eliminate each other, otherwise we wouldn't have this second sentence saying they can't do that

[Beta Rules](http://ninjadivision.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ninja-all-stars-public-beta-rulebook-sz1.pdf)

> Fire and Water eliminate each other.
>   Earth and Air eliminate each other.
>   Spirit and Void eliminate each other.
>
> When two dice eliminate each other, remove them from the pool of rolled dice. Dice that the attacker rolled can only eliminate dice that the defender rolled and vice versa. **All possible eliminations must be made.**
>
> Spirit: The attacker is Injured.
>   Fire:​All ninjas in the attacker’s influence zone, including the attacker, are stunned. (See Stun, page !X!)
>   Air:​The attacker may move the defender up to 3 spaces in any direction.
>   Water:The player who picked Water as the result may move the attacker up to 3 spaces in any direction. The defending player then places the defender in the attacker’s front influence zone.
>   Earth: ​The defender is stunned. (See Stun, page !X!)
>   Void: ​The defender is Injured.

Some examples:

Attacker rolls 2 Spirit and Defender rolls 2 Void

- Check for matches
- Find a match of 1 Spirit and 1 Void and remove
- Check for more matches
- Find a match of 1 Spirit and 1 Void and remove
- No more dice so attack results in nothing happening

Attacker rolls 3 Spirit and Defender rolls 2 Void

- Check for matches
- Find a match of 1 Spirit and 1 Void and remove
- Check for more matches
- Find a match of 1 Spirit and 1 Void and remove
- Check for matches
- Only 1 dice left and is Spirit so attacker is damaged

Attacker rolls 3 spirit, 1 Void and defender rolls 2 void

- Check for matches
- Find a match of 1 Spirit and 1 Void and remove 1 Spirit from attacker and 1 
  Void from defender
- Check for more matches
- Find a match of 1 Spirit and 1 Void and remove remove 1 Spirit from attacker and 1 Void from defender
- Check for matches
- The 1 Spirit and 1 Void that are left are in the attackers pool so not a match and the attacker can now chose which effect to use

Comment: The bolded text is nullified by the sentence exactly before it - you only ever nullify one dice *each*, so *who* has more dice never changes.

Comment: @vonBoomslang That is not the case as the second sentence just qualifies what a match is and isn't and the third sentence is informing you to remove all possible matches. I have updated my answer with some examples.